# Depth of nested ng-repeat — AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to get the depth of a nesting ng-repeats? Say if you are iterating over an nested object of unknown depth like nested comments?

Answer (score 3):

Since `ng-repeat` creates a new scope, you could do something like this.

`{{$depth = $parent.$depth && $parent.$depth + 1 || 1}}`

See https://jsfiddle.net/crgt25uk/ for a working example.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ExampleController',function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
        {name:'foo',items:[{name:'foofoo'},{name:'foobar'}]},
        {name:'bar',items:[{name:'barfoo'},{name:'barbar'}]}
    ]
})
```

And your template:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{$depth = $parent.$depth && $parent.$depth + 1 || 1}}: {{item.name}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in item.items">{{$depth = $parent.$depth && $parent.$depth + 1 || 1}}: {{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```